# How to iterate a big Json in Java that can have multiple level of Objects and Arrays without using a pojo class?

Tags: java, json, iteration

How to iterate a big Json in Java that can have multiple levels of Objects and Arrays without using a pojo class  for parsing? 
The objects and Array key names are unknown. Is there any common code that can do this ?
In this sample json all the data in value key has to be printed.
Sample Json :

```
"X": [
        {
            "Y": {
                "value": "Test"
            },
            "Z": {
                "value": 2
            }
}
]
```

The real json can be really big with multiple Array and object levels.

NB : Please don't mark this as duplicate as other questions are not about the exact requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jackson, you can read\load the `JSON` as follows:

```
private JsonNode loadJson(String json) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
    return rootNode;
}
```

Sample `JSON`:

```
{
  "name":{
    "first":"Tatu",
    "last":"Saloranta"
  },
  "title":"Jackson founder",
  "company":"FasterXML",
  "pets":[
    {
      "type":"dog",
      "number":1
    },
    {
      "type":"fish",
      "number":50
    }
  ]
}
```

To parse the `JSON`:

```
String json = "{\"name\": {\"first\":\"Tatu\",\"last\":\"Saloranta\"},\"title\":\"Jackson founder\",\"company\":\"FasterXML\",\"pets\":[{\"type\":\"dog\",\"number\":1},{\"type\":\"fish\",\"number\":50}]}";

JsonNode rootNode = loadJson(json);

JsonNode nameNode = rootNode.get("name");
String firstName = nameNode.get("first").asText();
String lastName = nameNode.get("last").asText();

String title = rootNode.get("title").asText();
String company = rootNode.get("company").asText();

JsonNode petsArrayNode = rootNode.get("pets");
for (final JsonNode petNode : petsArrayNode ) {
  String type = petNode.get("type").asText();
  int number = petNode.get("number").asInt();
}
```

You can read more here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jackson's Streaming API for that (it's also quite fast and modest on memory consumption):

- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi
- https://blog.overops.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

Answer (score 0):

You can read JSON as a stream with JsonParser from JSR 374 (JSON Processing API aka JSON-P):

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event;

public static class ParserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\"X\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"Y\": {\n" +
                "                \"value\": \"Test\"\n" +
                "            },\n" +
                "            \"Z\": {\n" +
                "                \"value\": 2\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "]}";
        JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(jsonString));
        String key = null;

        while (parser.hasNext()) {
            Event event = parser.next();

            switch (event) {
                case KEY_NAME:
                    key = parser.getString();
                    break;
                case VALUE_STRING:
                case VALUE_NUMBER:
                case VALUE_TRUE:
                case VALUE_FALSE:
                case VALUE_NULL:
                    System.out.println(key + ": " + parser.getString());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to include glassfish implementation

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Code sample taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-parse-a-json-string-using-streaming-api-in-java

You can read more about JSON-P here: https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hope this is what you were looking for.